# How to detect click on image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

guys, I'm currently making Chess in Python using Tkinter and wanted to know how to detect if an image is clicked?

This code adds a click function to each image I have stored within a dictionary

```
def MouseClickOnEachPiece(self, rows, columns, event): 

   global AllPieces

   while True:
     for ThePieces in AllPieces:
         if board[rows][columns] == ThePieces:
             self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', MakeMove)
         elif board[rows][columns] != ThePieces:
             continue
```

This code is used to make the move

```
def MakeMove(self, rows, columns, event):

    global AllPieces

    print("You have clicked at: ", event.x , event.y)

    while True:
        for i in AllPieces:
            if #the image is clicked : # -- What would i use to check if the image is clicked?
                canvas.move(i, #themove )
```

Comment: Surely for a chessboard all you have to do is check the click position? A simple calculation ought to tell you the exact board position.

Comment: The canvas has a `bind` method to all bindings to individual items on the canvas. This method is documented, and there are many questions and answers on this site related to bindings on canvas objects.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can use a button and place an image on the button instead.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

button = ttk.Button(root)
button.pack()

theImage = PhotoImage(file = "source")

button.config(image = theImage)
```

Comment: would the button be able to move with the picture if i use the .move function on it?

Comment: When this is done and you have an image that has transparent parts it comes up as white and not what the background colour is. I there any way to make the button transparent so all you could see is the image